# How to add items to NgModule entryComponents runtime?

Tags: angular, angular-services

I have the following piece of Angular code:

dashboard.component.ts

```
import {Component, AfterViewInit, ComponentFactoryResolver, ViewContainerRef, OnInit, Input} from "@angular/core";
import {WidgetItem} from "../modules/widget-item";
import {WidgetComponent} from "../modules/widget.component";
import {DashboardService} from "./dashboard.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'dashboard',
    templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    @Input() widgets: WidgetItem[];

    constructor(
        private dashboardService: DashboardService,
        private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
        private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.widgets = this.dashboardService.getWidgets();
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.loadDashboard();
    }

    private loadDashboard(): void {
        this.viewContainerRef.clear();
        if(this.widgets) {
            for (let widget of this.widgets) {
                let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(widget.component);
                let componentRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
                (<WidgetComponent>componentRef.instance).data = widget.data;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And dashboard.service.ts

```
import {Injectable}           from '@angular/core';
import {WidgetItem} from "../modules/widget-item";

@Injectable()
export class DashboardService {
    private dashboardWidgets: WidgetItem[];
    constructor() {
        this.dashboardWidgets = [];
    }

    getWidgets() {
        console.log('get widgets');
        return this.dashboardWidgets;
    }

    addWidget(widget: WidgetItem): void {
        console.log('add widget', widget);
        this.dashboardWidgets.push(widget);
    }
}
```

And contract-widget.component.ts

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {WidgetComponent} from "./widget.component";

@Component({
    selector: 'contract-widget',
    templateUrl: './contract-widget.component.html'
})

export class ContractWidgetComponent implements WidgetComponent {
    data: any;
}
```

And widget.component.ts

```
export interface WidgetComponent {
    data: any;
}
```

And widget-item.ts

```
import {Type} from "@angular/core";
export class WidgetItem {
    constructor(public component: Type<any>, public data:any) {}
}
```

What I try to do is dynamically load the widget on my dashboard using the componentfactoryresolver. This works perfectly when I manually add the ContractWidgetComponent to my app.component entryComponents. However, what I would like to accomplish is that I can load widgets onto my dashboard without knowing that they exists in my app. I have separated the code so my folder structure looks like this:

```
/app -- contains app.module.ts, app-routing.module.ts and app.component.ts
/app/parts -- contains dahsboard.component.ts and dahsboard.service.ts
/app/modules -- contains contract-widget.component.ts widget.component.ts and widget-item.ts
```

In my widgets I have also setup a component so I can use the component as loadChildren to dynamically load the component. (In my app/modules I do have more code with other components and services for specific functionality which aren't needed for explaining my problem here).

What I want to do is to be able to develop another module inside my /app/modules and just add the needed files there and have my dashboard be able to just display any new widget in my modules without changing code in my /app or /app/parts directory.

The main parts do work properly, but when I try to load the widgets on my dashboard with the `loadDashboard()` I get the following error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for ContractWidgetComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
Error: No component factory found for ContractWidgetComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
```

This makes sense, because I do not want to add the ContractWidgetComponent to my /app/app.module.ts entryComponents array, since my app do not know what types of widgets I will have (in the future).

Is there any way to programmatically add the ContractWidgetComponent to my entryComponent on **runtime** so I can load my widget dynamically on my dashboard?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: please consider accepting [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44562681/2545680)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I want to do is to be able to develop another module inside my
>   /app/modules and just add the needed files there and have my dashboard
>   be able to just display any new widget in my modules without changing
>   code in my /app or /app/parts directory.

Yes, you can do that. Just define a module with `contract-widget.component.ts` specified in module declarations, load that module dynamically and use `compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync` compiler API to generate all factories of the module. Then you can access these factories and instantiates components dynamically.

For more details, read [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e)

Comment: Nice! I forgot about the dynamic compilation part (even though I read your article several days ago). I'll delete my answer to avoid any confusion :)

Comment: @GeorgeK, yeah, how did you like the article? :)

Comment: I really like the whole series, to be honest :). A nice, detailed explanation of  some of the key concepts in Angular. Thanks for the good write ups :)

Comment: thanks for the kind words, it takes so much time but I'm glad the community benefits. I'm in the process of writing `Zones in depth` now, so do follow up to be notified when it's finished :)

Comment: Thank you for the help. It pushed me into the right direction!

Comment: A code example might make this a better answer. I have no idea what file(s) and interface(s) might be involved here.